# Calculating a difference between two columns within an UNPIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, ssms, unpivot

I am trying to perform an UNPIVOT, but one of my columns was actually the difference between two columns, and SSMS is not accepting that as one of the values in the creation of the un-pivoted field.

Example:

```
UNPIVOT(                                                                                                 
        Points
        for PointType in (                                                                                   
                          HomeTeamPoints
                        , (HomeTeamPoints - TotalPoints)
                        , TotalPoints

        ) as pnts
```

This works perfectly if I comment out the difference field, but once that's in it tells me "incorrect syntax near '('". Once i remove the parentheses it says "Incorrect Syntax near '-'"

Anyone know if there's a way to make this go through?

Thanks a lot

Comment: By bombs do you mean it gives an error?  If so what is the error?

Comment: Yes, sorry. If i have the parentheses is says "Incorrect syntax near '('" and if I remove the parentheses it says "incorrect syntax near '-'"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `unpivot`.  Use `apply`:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values ('HomeTeamPoints', HomeTeamPoints),
             ('Diff', HomeTeamPoints - TotalPoints),
             ('TotalPoints', TotalPoints)
     ) v(which, points);
```

`unpivot` is bespoke syntax that does only one thing.  `apply` implements *lateral join*s.  These are very powerful types of joins and are part of the standard.  Unpivoting is only the beginning of what you can do with `apply`.

Comment: This is it! Worked just like I wanted it to! Thank you so much... definitely tucking that away in my arsenal and reading up on when to use which

Comment: You come up with some of the best solutions I have ever seen Gordon!!